# Считается ли правомерным употребление феминитивов в русском языке?

Tags: выбор-слов

1. Являются ли нормой русского языка феминитивы, такие как авторка, редакторка, депутатка? Есть ли правило, подтверждающее уместность употребления подобных слов в русском языке, или феминитивы - это прихоть людей в феминистских движениях, не подкрепленная никакими нормами русского языка?
2. Если вышеперечисленные феминитивы не являются нормой, почему в русском языке есть такие слова, как спортсменка, акушерка, комсомолка?
3. Раньше такими словами, как докторша, профессорша, бригадирша, офицерша, обозначали женщин, которые были замужем за представителями конкретной профессии или рода деятельности. Например, бригадирша - жена бригадира, а докторша - жена доктора.

Изменилось ли значение подобных слов (докторша, офицерша и т.д.) в настоящее время?

Comment: Интересная статья здесь. http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=1.96

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русском языке существует **набор "женских суффиксов",** при этом выбор их зависит **от разных факторов** (фонетика слова и его сочетаемость с конкретным суффиксом, стиль речи, традиция употребления и др.)

**Основные суффиксы: ИЦ/НИЦ, К, Ш, ИХ и др.** https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/suffiksyi-oboznachayuschie-lits-jenskogo-62092.html

**Автор, редактор** – эти слова относятся к деловому или книжному стилю, они обозначают мужские и женские профессии. Суффикс К не подходит здесь даже для сниженного стиля, так как он многозначный (что такое авторка?), а редакторша – просто сниженный стиль.

Докторша, профессорша - также сниженный (неточный) стиль, так как может обозначать профессию и жену.

В традиционных названиях (портниха, ткачиха) суффикс ИХ закрепился, но сниженный характер ИХ и Ш является очень устойчивым, что ограничивает их применение.

Эта тема подробно изложена у Розенталя: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#з_03](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_03)

Comment: Вряд ли "кассирша", "секретарша" или "партнёрша" (по танцам) могут обозначать жён. Можно говорить об общей тенденции, но не  о правилах сортировки, относящих такие слова (как и напр. слово "портниха" с опальным суффиксом) к просторечиям, при всём почтении к Дитмару Эльяшевичу (он делает такое заключение строго по суффиксу: "все эти слова являются..."). В нормальной разговорной речи (да и в литературе - за пределами изысканных примеров Розенталя из советской прозы) приведённые примеры предпочитаются формальным наименованиям,

Comment: которые как раз и имеют ограничения в употреблении (даже при деловом общении женщина именуется "секретарём" только в штатном расписании). Всё очень индивидально. К "депутату" никакими правилами не приделать феминизирующий суффикс - любой вариант будет звучать пренебрежительно.

Comment: Всё очень индивидуально - с этой мысли я как раз и начала ответ. Опальный суффикс может использоваться для образования нейтральных по стилю слов, если другие суффиксы не подходят. (партнерша) .  Розенталь отмечает, что слова с суффиксом Ш  в наше время чаще обозначают профессию женщины, но всё-таки профессорша как жена профессора еще может встретиться  в разговорной речи. Вроде бы никаких противоречий и несоответствий между вашим мнением и мнением Розенталя я не вижу. Так что не так?

Comment: Мне не нравится радикальность обобщений у Розенталя (§148, п.3: "все эти слова являются просторечными" или принадлежат сниженному стилю); думаю, что к таким обобщениям нужно относиться оглядкой на сложившееся словоупотребление.

Comment: Ну из названных им слов можно, пожалуй,  выделить секретаршу и кассиршу, их статус повысился от просторечного до разговорного (в деловом стиле это по-прежнему секретарь и кассир). Розенталь обозначил общую тенденцию,  в то же время язык развивается, какие-то изменения всегда возможны внутри определенных групп.